# Is that valid to use while(true){ //Processes }?

Tags: java, performance

In the program that I am working on, I need to write small daemon-like processes to provide some small services on different threads. Is that valid to use something like that?

```
while(true) {

// Processes

}
```

Does it cause any problem in the program for performance stand point? And what are alternatives?

Comment: That is on purpose to do repeated jobs

Comment: use a scheduler instead with your task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much better to use a `ScheduledExecutorService` and program it on repeat. Likely you want `scheduleWithFixedDelay` which pauses between tasks.

An infinite loop with no blocking at all can drain your CPU.  This is not dangerous though:

```
while(true) {
    // work
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```